# Moving to new site with different url structure

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect my olddomain to newdomain.right now we use below htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Except below url structure

```
olddomain.com/blog/intro/.... must redirect to newdomain.com/intro/....
```

Comment: You simply implement the exceptions (more specific rules) prior to more general rules. That is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in comment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/intro/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/intro/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```